# Show that there exist an open set $V$ containing $s=1$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $$m=\lim_{s→1}\frac{(s-1)f′(s)}{f(s)}$$ where $f$ is an analytic function with $s=1$ as a zero of order $m$.

My **question** is: By using the definition of the limit show that there exist an open set $V$ containing $s=1$ such that $$((s-1)f′(s))/f(s)≤m$$

Comment: You need more conditions to constrain $f$. If $f=(s-1)^m\cdot g$, $\frac{(s-1)f'(s)}{f(s)}=m+\frac{(s-1)g'(s)}{g(s)}$, that means we should have $\frac{(s-1)g'(s)}{g(s)}<0$ on open set $V$.

Comment: We should have $\frac{(s-1)g'(s)}{g(s)}<0$ on open set $V$. But $g(1)\neq 0$,so in small neighborhood $g(1)$ doesn't change sign, so $g'(s)$ must have the opposite sign when $s<1$ and $s>1$. Because $g$ is analytic, we have $g'(1)=0$, so if $g(1)>0$, then $s=1$ is a local maximum, if $g(1)<0$, then $s=1$ is a local minimum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general no such set exists. Let $f(s)=e^s(s-1)^m$. Then
$$
\frac{(s-1)f'(s)}{f(s)}=s-1+m>m \text{ if } s>1.
$$